# How to prevent click event for mouseup event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is a `rect` on `mousedown mouseup click` event . but when I click the rect mouseup Event dosen`t trigger   https://jsfiddle.net/f0vbc94s/
there is my code:

```
var rect=d3.select(".text").append("rect")
                    .attr("width",1000).attr("height",1000)
          .style("fill","#00ff00");
rect.on("click",function(){
        d3.event.preventDefault
        d3.select(this).style("fill","#000000")
})
.on("mousedown",function(){
        d3.select(this).style("fill","#ff0000")
}).on("mouseup",function(){
        d3.event.preventDefault;
        d3.select(this).style("fill","#00ff00")
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your `click` event is overwriting the `mouseup` event. When you click
>   and hold the mouse at down position, `mousedown` event fires and
>   changed the color. When you release the mouse, `mouseup` event fired,
>   changed the color and then `click` event fired immediately and changed
>   the color. So you couldn't recognise it.

If you comment the `click` event, you can see the `mouseup` event fired.

Try this,

```
var rect=d3.select(".text").append("rect")
                    .attr("width",1000).attr("height",1000)
          .style("fill","#00ff00");
//rect.on("click",function(){
        //d3.event.preventDefault
        //d3.select(this).style("fill","#000000")
//})
rect.on("mousedown",function(){
        d3.select(this).style("fill","#ff0000")
}).on("mouseup",function(){
        d3.event.preventDefault;
        d3.select(this).style("fill","#00ff00")
})
```

Comment: but I need click Event to do other things. How to deal this?

Comment: You can't have `mouseup` and `click` event for the same purpose like changing color. You can do different things. Whats your actual purpose and issue?

Comment: mouseup can  trigger at a the different location I deal this things, thank you